# How can I restrict textfield

Tags: javascript

I want to create `TextField` it allows only numbers.For this I written the following code but it's not working.

script code:

```
 function numberTextField(){
var keyAsciiValue=event.keyCode||event.which;
console.log(keyAsciiValue);
if (keyAsciiValue>=48&&keyAsciiValue<=57) {
    console.log("This is Number");
    return true;
}else{
    console.log("This is Not a Number");
    return false;
};
}
```

html code:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="numberTextField()" placeholder="NoOfRows" id="fieldsCount2"/>
```

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: <input type="number" name="whatever" min="1" max="5">

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/14/

Comment: @Mr.Alien What you suggested,it's working fine. But I didn't understand syntax of first 2 lines.`evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I likes your suggestion, But I can't able to like your comment.

Comment: @user2873816 No problem, and I am not a JS foo, so can't explain the meaning of that line :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberTextField(evt)
{
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
   {
         console.log("This is Not a Number");
         return false;
   }
   else
   {
          console.log("This is a Number");
          return true;
   }         


}
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return numberTextField(event)" placeholder="NoOfRows" id="fieldsCount2"/>
```

Comment: you written 2 return statements.`retuen true` is belongs to else condition

Comment: updated answer also not working.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add return in onkeypress.Now it should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

updated code:

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeypress="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]$/,'')"  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]$/,'')" placeholder="NoOfRows" id="fieldsCount2"/>
```

Comment: not working properly, just enter a char and immediately enter a number.

Comment: Or just press any key like 'a' and don't release it.

Comment: Thanks for finding the fault..Check the updated code...Hope it will change your mind.:)